# Access DataTable's Default SearchBox in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I want to set the text of search box of datatable based on a checkbox. But not able to access that using $scope.dtInstance as it is coming null.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-click="rerenderTable()">test</p>
<table id="tableid" datatable="ng" dt-options="st.dtOptions" dt-instance="st.dtInstance" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" ng-if="st">
<!--Table Data-->
</table>
```

I want to access the default Search box and set its value through code but not getting any idea.
I have tried this but no success.

```
$scope.dtInstance.DataTable.search('text');
$scope.dtInstance.DataTable.search('text').draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i was not instantiating the instance and that is why dtInstance was not working.

Here is the updated code from above.

```
<p><input type="checkbox" ng-click="rerenderTable()">test</p>
<table id="tableid" datatable="ng" dt-options="st.dtOptions" dt-instance="st.dtIntanceCallback" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" ng-if="st">
<!--Table Data-->
</table>
```

in Controller Initialise the dtInstance

```
$scope.dtInstance = {};
```

and create new function as

```
$scope.dtIntanceCallback = function(instance){
        $scope.dtInstance = instance;
    }
```

now i am able to access instance in my rerenderTable function.